# how to add values to css properties at runtime?

Tags: jquery, css

I have created one css file. In that I write one class say "HtmlElement". In that I want to assign value to the css property "left" which is calculated at runtime. so my question is how can I assign a value to css property at runtime in jquery? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

not directly possible but you can add a css to all elements which are using that class

```
$(".yourclass").css({left:"25px"});
```

or (but this implicitly add `px` unit)

```
$(".yourclass").css({left:25});
```

this will set css in style. check [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more information

Comment: if a single attribute added to css then `{}` is not necessary. but you write is called best practice :)

Comment: you also don't have to write '25px', just 25 as number is enough (even negatives like -25)

Answer (score 0):

plain JS:

```
document.getElementById("myElementsId").style.left = "400px";
```

in jQuery like:

```
$('.class').css('left', '50px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQuery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

Answer (score 0):

you can add inline css with help of jQuery like below

```
  $('.HtmlElement').css('left','20px');
```

see [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class').css({
'color','#555555',
'border','1px solid blue'
});
```